# Debugger Windows 7

Tags: windows, debugging

I am looking for a debugger like ddd in ubuntu for windows. I need this to debug c++ files. Not able to find any good ones. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you evaluated so far? Why did you decide that they weren't "good ones"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debugging tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009).

[Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).